# Reponsive email template for gmail - media queries in head doesn't work

Tags: html, css, email

I'm struggling with creating an email template "from scratch" (that I then copy paste in mailchimp as their CMS is not appropriate to what I have to do).

The general email looks good except a

text - image with `width 50%` that has to become:

image

text

With `width: 100%`

```
.responsive-width {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .responsive-width {
      width: 100% !important;
      min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}



<td valign="top" style="padding: 0!important;">
  <table class="responsive-width" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="align-mid" style="padding: 0!important;text-align: center !important;">
        <img src="myimg-url.jpg" alt="newsletter photo cover">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="responsive-width" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0!important;">
        <h2 class="no-top">Title!</h2>
        <div class="grey other-font">
          TEXT
          <br>
          <a class="btn align-mid button-orange read-more left" href="">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

I removed the inline-style for more visibility.

The media query is in the `<head>`, within a `<style>` element.
But I heard that it's not supported by gmail.

How am I supposed to make it responsive then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all inline, like this.

```
<img src="myimg-url.jpg" width="480" alt="..." border="0" style="width:100%; max-width:480px;">
```

Then, this way you have a fully responsive image and can avoid some of those client inconsistencies.

Additionally, you could add a class and target that element like this;

```
img.thumbnail{
   max-width:480px !important;
   width: 100% !important;
}
```